# pip and conda environment.yml: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'list'

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install a package with pip inside a conda env.
So I have an `environment.yml` file as follows:

```
name: test-env

dependencies:
    - pip:
        - "git+https://github.com/choldgraf/download"
```

But when I run `conda env update --file environment.yml`, I get:

```
Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: An unexpected error has occurred.
Please consider posting the following information to the
conda GitHub issue tracker at:

# Here some configuration that I omit    

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mathurin/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 634, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mathurin/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main_update.py", line 106, in execute
    installer.install(prefix, specs, args, env, prune=args.prune)
  File "/home/mathurin/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda_env/installers/pip.py", line 8, in install
    pip_cmd = pip_args(prefix) + ['install', ] + specs
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'list'
```

However, just typing `pip install git+https://github.com/choldgraf/download` in my bash console works fine. What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT: my first thought was to update conda. I am now at version 4.3.23, and trying to `conda update conda` yields:

```
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at ~/anaconda3:
#
conda                     4.3.23                   py35_0    conda-forge
```

Comment: What version of `conda` do you have?

Comment: What if you update conda? The version I have is 4.3.25

Comment: Ah, you have installed from `conda-forge`. If you want to update that, you can type `conda install conda=4.3.25` and see if it solves the problem, although it might not...

Comment: @darthbith Updating like that and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I've found a solution. You have to add at least one dependency to your configuration (I'm not sure if it has to be pip). In my configuration I've added `pip=9.0.1=py35_1`

```
name: myenv
channels:
- defaults
dependencies:
- pip=9.0.1=py35_1
- pip:
  - tqdm==4.19.5
```

So I think in your case it would be something like:

```
name: test-env
dependencies:
- pip=9.0.1=py35_1
- pip:
  - "git+https://github.com/choldgraf/download"
```